# How to name the "superscriptions" of dimensions in r?

Tags: r

perhaps a dumb question, yet I cannot find an answer.
If I make a mosaic plot with a vcd package so:

```
 library(vcd)
 test<-matrix(c(65,31,495,651), ncol=2,byrow=T)
 colnames(test)<-c("2010", "2011")
 rownames(test)<-c("yes", "now")
 mosaic(test, shade=T, legend=T)
```

it works like a charm except that the superscriptions over the years and the outputs (yes/no) are shown "A" and "B".

I would like to name these "Years" and "Outputs" but I cannot find a parameter for this.
How could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify dimnames this way :

```
dimnames(test) <- list(foo=colnames(test),bar=rownames(test))
mosaic(test, shade=T, legend=T)
```

[image]

In fact, `mosaic` is better suited to be applied to contingency tables, where the labels are determined by the `table` function :

```
color <- sample(c("red","blue"),10,replace=TRUE)
color2 <- sample(c("yellow","green"),10,replace=TRUE)
tab <- table(color,color2)
mosaic(tab, shade=T)
```

[image]